# Filter Pandas dataframe based on strict inequality and missing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I am new to Pandas. How do I filter based on either a strict inequality or missing data? In the code below I want `one` to be either above a threshold or missing. How do I achieve this? Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {
    'one' : [1.1, np.nan, 3.1],
    'two' : [3.2, 2.2, 1.2],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

for one in np.arange(0, 6, 1.):
    df1 = df[(df['one']>one) | (df['one']==np.nan)]
    if len(df1) == 0:
        continue
    for two in np.arange(0, 6, 1.):
        df2 = df1[(df1['two']>two)]
        if len(df2) == 0:
            continue
        print(one, two, len(df2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [isnull()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) function to identify missing values.

```
df.loc[(df['one'] > 2) | (df['one'].isnull())]

#    one  two
# 1  NaN  2.2
# 2  3.1  1.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution, which first fills (using [fillna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) method) NaNs with the value which would satisfy your condition:

```
In [101]: df.loc[df.one.fillna(3) > 2]
Out[101]:
   one  two
1  NaN  2.2
2  3.1  1.2
```